# php Get the original key value in in_array multidimensional

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have a multidimensional array with some duplicate sub-arrays:

```
 $data = array(
    2 => array  (
            'User'      => 'cat',
            'File_name' => 'cat.docx',
            'Document'  => 'Document1',
            'Date'      => '2017-03-02',
            'Pages'     => 1
        ),
    3 => array  (
            'User'      => 'dog',
            'File_name' => 'dog.docx',
            'Document'  => 'Document2',
            'Date'      => '2017-03-02',
            'Pages'     => 3
        ),
    4 => array  (
            'User'      => 'shark',
            'File_name' => 'shark.docx',
            'Document'  => 'Document3',
            'Date'      => '2017-03-01',
            'Pages'     => 5
        ),
    5 => array  (
            'User'      => 'dog',
            'File_name' => 'dog.docx',
            'Document'  => 'Document2',
            'Date'      => '2017-03-02',
            'Pages'     => 3
    ),
    6 => array  (
            'User'      => 'dog',
            'File_name' => 'dog.docx',
            'Document'  => 'Document2',
            'Date'      => '2017-03-02',
            'Pages'     => 3
    ),
    //...
);
```

I could recognize which items are duplicated with:

```
$final = $dupli = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $array ) {
    if(!in_array($array, $final)){
        $final[$key] = $array;
    }
    else
    {
        $dupli[$key] = $array;
    }
}
print_r($dupli);
```

But I would like to know what index was the first subarray (the key of this) found, as a message, for example:

```
 $final = $dupli = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $array ) {
        if(!in_array($array, $final)){
            $final[$key] = $array;
        }
        else
        {
            $dupli[$key] = $array;
            echo "Line " . $key . " duplicated row, the original row is: " . $originalkey;
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Line 5 duplicated row, the original row is: 3 
Line 6 duplicated row, the original row is: 3
```

Comment: when user = cat, does that mean the other values are equal too, or could they be different?

Comment: All items in sub array must be equal

Comment: I understand but in your example, for all records with user=cat for example the other elements of the subarray are equal. Is that always true or could a subarray also be `user=cat, file_name=xmas.docx, document=somethingelse` and so on

Comment: The user and the filename (and the rest) are not related, it's only and example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the key that has a specific value, you can use `array_search()`.

So, to fetch the key from the final array, this should do it in your `else` statement:

```
$dupli[$key] = $array;
$originalkey = array_search($array, $final);
echo "Line " . $key . " duplicated row, the original row is: " . $originalkey . "\n";
```

[Read more about `array_search()` in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Answer (score 0):

As Magnus Eriksson said you can use array_search, if you use it instead of in_array in your existing cycle you can do the operation only once per cycle:

```
 $final = $dupli = array();
 foreach ($data as $key => $array ) {
    if(($originalkey = array_search($array, $final)) === false){
        $final[$key] = $array;
    }
    else
    {
        $dupli[$key] = $array;
        echo "Line " . $key . " duplicated row, the original row is: " . $originalkey;
    }
}
```

Comment: your logic is backwards

Answer (score 0):

Using  [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) along with loop you can simplify your code like below :

```
foreach($data as $index => $value)
{
    $key = array_search($value, $data);
    if($key!==false && $key != $index){
        printf("Line %d duplicated row, the original row is: %d\n",$index, $key);
    }
}
```

**Test results on CLI**

**Script**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test.php 
<?php
$data = array(
    2 => array  (
            'User'      => 'cat',
            'File_name' => 'cat.docx',
            'Document'  => 'Document1',
            'Date'      => '2017-03-02',
            'Pages'     => 1
        ),
    3 => array  (
            'User'      => 'dog',
            'File_name' => 'dog.docx',
            'Document'  => 'Document2',
            'Date'      => '2017-03-02',
            'Pages'     => 3
        ),
    4 => array  (
            'User'      => 'shark',
            'File_name' => 'shark.docx',
            'Document'  => 'Document3',
            'Date'      => '2017-03-01',
            'Pages'     => 5
        ),
    5 => array  (
            'User'      => 'dog',
            'File_name' => 'dog.docx',
            'Document'  => 'Document2',
            'Date'      => '2017-03-02',
            'Pages'     => 3
    ),
    6 => array  (
            'User'      => 'dog',
            'File_name' => 'dog.docx',
            'Document'  => 'Document2',
            'Date'      => '2017-03-02',
            'Pages'     => 3
    ),
    //...
);


foreach($data as $index => $value)
{
    $key = array_search($value, $data);
    if($key!==false && $key != $index){
        printf("Line %d duplicated row, the original row is: %d\n",$index, $key);
    }
}



?>
```

**Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php test.php 
Line 5 duplicated row, the original row is: 3
Line 6 duplicated row, the original row is: 3
```